# Como pedir novo login quando a sessão expira?

Tags: session, genexus

Nas minhas Apps "online" eu uso bastantes variáveis websession.
Quando a sessão expira por falta de uso, a App fica inutilizável porque muitos parametros desaparecem.

Eu quero lançar uma msg pedido novo login, quando a sessão expira. Mas, como conseguir isso?

Se eu uso o evento Refresh para validar a sessão, não poderei lançar a msg, certo?

Comment: Você não esta utilizando o módulo GAM ? No link a seguir explica-se como configurar os parâmetros de timeout, e quando isso acontecer deveria apresentar-se automaticamente o login.
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?16338

Comment: Pablo, muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu não controlo a autenticação, apenas envio um request para um serviço externo que determinará se o user tem acesso ou não. Posso usar GAM nesse contexto?

Comment: Parece ser o cenário 4 comentado neste documento:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?15937